# how to get data from the database based on the datetime where is given is only the date?

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

I am trying to retrieve data from the database between 2 dates where they stored in the database as a datetime field not a date.

I am giving inputs as a string to be as a date such as:
20/06/2019 to 22/06/2019
then I convert the string to date time using the following code:

```
string fromDate= "20/06/2019";
string toDate= "22/06/2019";
DateTime OfromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime OtoDate = DateTime.ParseExact(toDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

then I pass the datetime to the method by this query which I think where is the issue at

```
     command.CommandText = string.Format("select * from tableDates where TRUNC(DATE_M) BETWEEN TO_DATE('{0}','DD-MON-RRRR') AND TO_DATE('{1}','DD-MON-RRRR')", fromDate, toDate);
```

note I am trying to retrieve all the data between 20/06/2019 to 22/06/2019

Comment: Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Pretty sure your issue is trying to pass dates as strings. If you stick to actual dates then everything should sort itself out. As @stickybit says, use date parameters and life will be easier.

Comment: @stickybit I'm not sure how to use it is it possible that you explain further more

Answer (score 0):

Your date string has the format `DD/MM/RRRR` and you are using the format model `DD-MON-RRRR`. The separators are not an issue but Oracle's [String-to-Date conversion rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51077) specifies that:

> - `MM` matches `MON` or `MONTH`
> - `MON` matches `MONTH`
> - `MONTH` matches `MON`

It does not specify that `MON` matches `MM` so:

```
select *
from   tableDates
where  TRUNC(DATE_M) BETWEEN TO_DATE('20/06/2019','DD-MON-RRRR')
                     AND     TO_DATE('20/06/2019','DD-MON-RRRR')
```

Will result in:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

If you change your format model to `MM` then:

```
select *
from   tableDates
where  TRUNC(DATE_M) BETWEEN TO_DATE('20/06/2019','DD-MM-RRRR')
                     AND     TO_DATE('20/06/2019','DD-MM-RRRR')
```

Will work.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ceb4a6729bd17956dd6d75cc6bbfadca)*

Answer (score -1):

Use datediff and use store procedures and pass parameters as date or date time. Datediff have many option to get difference between months and day year and many more.